# change background color of div if it contains an href that contains a specific string with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to take a list of hrefs and change the color of one of them if a word in the current url exists in the href. The challenging part is that all of the divs have the same class and can't be changed. Everything I've tried either changes all of them or none of them. Here's the code I have:

```
<div id="links">
    <div class="box"><a href="example.com/carolina">Link One</a></div>
    <div class="box"><a href="example.com/virgina">Link Two</a></div>
    <div class="box"><a href="example.com/georgia">Link Three</a></div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split('/');
    $(".box").each(function(){
        if (window.location.href.indexOf(pathArray[1]) > -1) {
            $(this).css('background', 'red');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Assuming that the current URL is: example.com/virgina/contact.html I would expect the middle div's background to change to red. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing current URL to the current URL, not the current URL to the link HREF.

Change

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf(pathArray[1]) > -1) {
```

to

```
if ($(this).children('a').attr('href').indexOf(pathArray[1]) > -1) {
```

Or you could replace the whole `each()` with just:

```
$('.box:has(a[href*="'+pathArray[1]+'"]').css('background', 'red');
```